# Outer Apply conversion in oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

SQL to oracle conversion of outer apply.

I have the following SQL query :

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[uvw_Templates_RecHist]
    AS
    SELECT RH.company_id
         , CI.company_name
         , RH.rec_date
         , RH.rec_code
         , RH.analyst_id
         , previous_rec_date = LRH.rec_date
         , previous_rec_code = LRH.rec_code
         , previous_analyst_id = LRH.analyst_id
         , [status] = CASE WHEN LRH.rec_date IS NULL THEN 'NEW'
                           WHEN RH.rec_code <> LRH.rec_code THEN 'CHANGE'
                           ELSE '' END
         , load_date = LoadDate
    FROM dbo.tblRecHist RH

    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblCompInd CI 
    ON RH.company_id = CI.company_id

    OUTER APPLY (
             SELECT A.company_id, A.rec_date, A.rec_code, A.analyst_id
             FROM dbo.tblRecHist A
             JOIN (
                   SELECT company_id, rec_date = MAX(rec_date) 
                   FROM dbo.tblRecHist WHERE rec_date < RH.rec_date
                   GROUP BY company_id
                   ) B
             ON A.company_id = B.company_id AND A.rec_date = B.rec_date
             WHERE A.company_id = RH.company_id
     ) LRH

    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT LoadDate = MAX(LoadDate), AnalystID = MAX(AnalystName), 
              RecDate, CompanyID
       FROM dbo.tblTemplates_LoadLog 
       WHERE Loaded = 1
       GROUP BY RecDate, CompanyID
    )LL
    ON RH.company_id = LL.CompanyID AND RH.rec_date = LL.RecDate
```

which i converted to below oracle query:

```
    CREATE VIEW uvw_Templates_RecHist
    AS
    SELECT RH.company_id
         , CI.company_name
         , RH.rec_date
         , RH.rec_code
         , RH.analyst_id
         , LRH.rec_date
         , LRH.rec_code
         , LRH.analyst_id
         , CASE WHEN LRH.rec_date IS NULL THEN 'NEW'
                WHEN RH.rec_code <> LRH.rec_code THEN 'CHANGE'
                ELSE '' END
         , LoadDate as load_date
    FROM tblRecHist RH

    LEFT JOIN tblCompInd CI 
    ON RH.company_id = CI.company_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT A.company_id, A.rec_date, A.rec_code, A.analyst_id
          FROM tblRecHist A
          JOIN (
            SELECT company_id, MAX(rec_date) 
            FROM tblRecHist WHERE rec_date < RH.rec_date
            GROUP BY company_id
            ) B
          ON A.company_id = B.company_id AND A.rec_date = B.rec_date
          WHERE A.company_id = RH.company_id
      ) LRH
     ON LRH.company_id=CI.company_id

    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(LoadDate), MAX(AnalystName), RecDate, CompanyID
    FROM tblTemplates_LoadLog 
    WHERE Loaded = 1
    GROUP BY RecDate, CompanyID
    )LL
    ON RH.company_id = LL.CompanyID AND RH.rec_date = LL.RecDate
```

but when i am running the oracle query i am getting the below error:

ORA-00904: "RH"."REC_DATE": invalid identifier

1.Why is this error coming even though there is no compile time error.
2.How to solve this?Is there other way we can convert the query from SQL to oracle.

Comment: What exact version of Oracle?  Google found the following for me, but it's for 12c, so what do you have?  https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1

Comment: version 11.0.0.116

Comment: As far as I know lateral queries have pretty much the exact same syntax in Oracle compared to SQL Server. Oracle 12c implements lateral queries, so I guess you are out of luck if using Oracle 11.

Comment: "11.0.0.116" doesn't come up anywhere as an option on Oracle's, or even on Google. Even the 11.2 version of Oracle version is ancient and past it's premium support date. That means it no longer gets basic bugfix or patches. Even extended support expires at the end of the year, and that's a **really big deal** because it also makes it difficult to even get basic _security_ fixes. When you can't get security fixes, you need to move on. Migrating to a more recently release **before** the end of the year is JOB #1 here. Do that, and this query should run unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your subquery for LRH is simply getting the previous row from tblRecHist. This might be a place to use LAG, since you're looking for 1 row prior in the same table.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

Assuming company_id, rec_date is unique, your query might look something like the following. Not tested since I don't have your database:

```
SELECT A.*
    ,CASE 
        WHEN previous_rec_date IS NULL
            THEN 'NEW'
        WHEN rec_code <> previous_rec_code
            THEN 'CHANGE'
        ELSE ''
        END
FROM (
    SELECT RH.company_id
        ,CI.company_name
        ,RH.rec_date
        ,RH.rec_code
        ,RH.analyst_id
        ,LAG(RH.rec_date) OVER (
            PARTITION BY RH.company_id ORDER BY rec_date
            ) AS previous_rec_date
        ,LAG(RH.rec_code) OVER (
            PARTITION BY RH.company_id ORDER BY rec_date
            ) AS previous_rec_code
        ,LAG(analyst_id) OVER (
            PARTITION BY RH.company_id ORDER BY rec_date
            ) AS previous_analyst_id
        ,LoadDate AS load_date
    FROM tblRecHist RH
    LEFT JOIN tblCompInd CI ON RH.company_id = CI.company_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(LoadDate) LoadDate
            ,MAX(AnalystName) AnalystName
            ,RecDate
            ,CompanyID
        FROM tblTemplates_LoadLog
        WHERE Loaded = 1
        GROUP BY RecDate
            ,CompanyID
        ) LL ON RH.company_id = LL.CompanyID
        AND RH.rec_date = LL.RecDate
    ) A
```

Nested the query so as to avoid repeating the "over(partion by . . . )" part in the case to get 'NEW' and 'CHANGE'.